# does not exist error in django when trying to delete a user from the admin panel

Tags: python, django

I am using Django signals I get this type of error when I try to delete a user from the admin panel

[image]

These is my signal.py file:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

def createProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print("Profile signal triggered")
    if created:
        user = instance
        profile = Profile.objects.create(
        user=user, username=user.username, email=user.email, name=user.first_name,
    )


def deleteUser(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance.user
    user.delete()


post_save.connect(createProfile, sender=User)
post_delete.connect(deleteUser, sender=Profile)
```

and here is my models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        upload_to="profiles/",
        default="profiles/user-default.png",
    )
    social_github = models.URLField(
        blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_url_github]
    )
    social_twitter = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_url_twitter]
    )
    social_linkedin = models.CharField(
       max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_url_linkedin]
    )
    social_youtube = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_url_yt]
    ) 
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(
    default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False
   )

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.username)
```

and here is my app.py file

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

**Please answer why do I get this type of error when I try to delete a user from the admin panel**

Comment: When you delete `user` object from admin, `profile` associated with that user is also deleted. Now when profile is deleted due to `post_delete` signal, `deleteUser` receiver is called, which tries to delete the user associated with the profile, but since `user` is already deleted, it throws the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out might it work for you are allowing profile without having a user by use of `null=True and blank=True`.So try to remove that and run the migration.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If it does not work for you please let me know